# Docker WCF net.pipe

Tags: wcf, docker, iis, dockerfile, net.pipe

I am trying to use net.pipe but have had no luck getting it to work with docker.  I have this working with a Windows Server 2016 VM running IIS no problem. Any information or samples on how to get this working would be very helpful!

Server Information
OS: Windows Server 2016
DockerFile: FROM microsoft/windowsservercore
Docker for Windows

Internet -> Ports 80 and 443 -> ASP.NET MVC Front End -> net.pipe -> WCF Service

WCF End Point

DockerFile

```
RUN Install-WindowsFeature -name NET-WCF-Pipe-Activation45
RUN Import-Module "WebAdministration"; 
New-Item IIS:\AppPools\NewPool; 
New-Item IIS:\Sites\NewSite -physicalPath 'C:\Service' -bindings @{protocol='https';bindingInformation='*:19001:'}; 
New-ItemProperty 'IIS:\Sites\NewSite' -name bindings -Value @{protocol='net.pipe';bindingInformation='localhost/servicelocation'}; 
Set-ItemProperty IIS:\Sites\NewSite -name applicationPool -value NewPool; 
Set-ItemProperty IIS:\Sites\NewSite -name EnabledProtocols -Value 'http,net.pipe'
```

Comment: I am currently having a very similar issue. Did you find any solution?

Comment: Add -Force to the end of the net.pipe binding. Since I added the net pipe first without a http binding it was getting removed. This fixed the issue for me.